Will a disk format resolve SMART error "1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors"?
Proxmox is reporting a SMART error "1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors" on a WD 2TB spinning drive. As the data on this drive is non-critical, would a format fix this (and mark the sector as unavailable)?
smartctl -a reports this:
Vendor:               QEMU
Product:              QEMU HARDDISK
Revision:             2.5+
Compliance:           SPC-3
User Capacity:        2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is thin provisioned, LBPRZ=0
Device type:          disk
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C
Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging

Interesting that this reports "device lacks SMART capability" when I'm getting a daily email from Proxmox reporting a SMART error on the drive.
Is there a better way of getting SMART info on the state of the drive, and fixing the sector in question (i.e. marking it as unavailable)?

With a SMART enabled drive, typically rewriting the bad block will cause the drive to replace it.
However, if the drive is out of replacement blocks, lit won't be able to fix it, and the drive is likely to catastrophically fail very soon.  Examination of the complete output from smartctl -a  on the device would be a good idea.  If the drive has recently developed a large number of bad blocks, has failed its internal self test, or is out of replacement blocks, it may fail very soon.

To see if the self test has failed is easy. How do you see the recent development of large numbers of bad blocks of if it is out replacement blocks?

smartctl -a reports this:
Vendor:               QEMU
Product:              QEMU HARDDISK
Revision:             2.5+
Compliance:           SPC-3
User Capacity:        2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is thin provisioned, LBPRZ=0
Device type:          disk
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C
Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging

that formatting is a mess.  You should add it to your question instead of a comment.

If the drive supports SMART usually it will tell you number of errors and replaced blocks, and sometimes what percentage of replaced blocks are left, along with critical error reports.
